# How to loop User Defined Data Types in SQL and pass parameters to Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

Consider I have below User Defined Data Type:

```
CREATE Type udt_MyType as Table(
@ID int,
@Name varchar(20),
@Address varchar(100)
)
```

Consider I have stored Procedure as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_MyProc (
 @ID int,
 @Name varchar(20),
 @Address varchar(100)
)
----Some Execution----
```

Now I want to create new Procdure which call above sp_MyProc by looping on udt_MyType
(***But without doing any changes to sp_MyProc)
So I want something like below:

```
CREATE Procedure sp_NewProc(
@udt as udt_MyType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
     WHILE LOOP on @udt   ----to get each row
     BEGIN
     exec sp_MyProc @udt.ID,@udt.Name,@udt.Address
     NEXT
     END
END
```

Note : I dont have permission to change sp_MyProc
Is it possible to achieve sp_NewProc? I want to loop on UDT and pass parameters to procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cursor instead of a while loop.

```
CREATE Procedure sp_NewProc(
@udt as udt_MyType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID int,
    @Name varchar(20),
    @Address varchar(100)
    
    Declare cursor_A cursor
    For Select * from @udt
    
    Begin
        OPEN cursor_A
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_A INTO @ID, @Name, @Address;
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                -- To DO Logic
                exec sp_MyProc @ID,@Name,@Address

                FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_A INTO @ID, @Name, @Address;
            END;
    
            CLOSE cursor_A;
            DEALLOCATE cursor_A;
    End;
End;
```

Comment: This is good when we have 3-4 parameters. But my actual procedure has 10-12 parameters. and I have 6 such SPs which I need to call one by one similarly as mentioned above. SO is there any way to avoid declaring parameters explicitly and fetch from UDT (like @udt.ID,@udt.Name etc)